# How to replace checked JCheckbox with the JTextField info

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I'm making this client formula and the list of clients is displayed in a `JTable` and sent to my SQL Database. I want a option saying if there is no name yet (a newborn, new business etc.) then the `JCheckbox` "unknown" is checked instead of filling the name in the `JtextField` area.

I think I should use the `if-else` statement.

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/num klienter", "root", "");    
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO klient (Name,Birthday,Description) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        if (unknownCB.isSelected()) {??what code to insert here??}

        else { pst.setString(1, nameTxt.getText());}
        pst.setString(2, dayTxt.getText()+"-" + monthTxt.getText()+"-" + yearTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(3, descriptionTxt.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved in database");
        upDateDB();
        
                }catch (Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex); 
    }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this worked:

```
if (unknownCB.isSelected()) {pst.setString(1, "unknown");
    } else { pst.setString(1, nameTxt.getText());
    }
```